# Authentication in Express. Property 'comparePassword' does not exist on type 'Document'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express, mongoose

I am new to express and node.js. I am trying to build an authentication system without frontend. I am using typescript, passport, passport-local and mongoose. I get the following errors :

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
auth.ts:20:37 - error TS2339: Property 'comparePassword' does not exist on type 'Document'.

20       const passwordOK = await user.comparePassword(password);
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
auth.ts:32:19 - error TS2339: Property '_id' does not exist on type 'Model<Document, {}>'.

32   done(null, user._id);
                     ~~~
```

and this is my code auth.ts

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import passport from "passport";
import mongoose, { Document } from "mongoose";
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
//const UserModel = require("./src/models/crmModel");
import { UserSchema } from "./src/models/crmModel";
const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: "email" }, async function (
    username: string,
    password: string,
    done: Function
  ) {
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ email: username }).exec();
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: "Invalid username or password" });
      }
      const passwordOK = await user.comparePassword(password);
      if (!passwordOK) {
        return done(null, false, { message: "Invalid username or password" });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    } catch (err) {
      return done(err);
    }
  })
);

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user._id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(id).exec();
    return done(null, user);
  } catch (err) {
    return done(err);
  }
});

module.exports = {
  initialize: passport.initialize(),
  session: passport.session(),
  setUser: (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    res.locals.user = req.user;
    return next();
  },
};
```

this is my crmModel.ts code

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import * as EmailValidator from "email-validator";
import { NextFunction } from "express";
import { Document } from "mongoose";
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const SALT_ROUNDS = 12;

interface props extends Document {
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

export const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      index: { unique: true },
      minlength: 3,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      lowercase: true,
      index: { unique: true },
      validate: {
        validator: EmailValidator.validate,
        message: (props) => `${props.value} is not valid email address!`,
      },
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      index: { unique: true },
      minlength: 8,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
).pre<props>("save", async function (next) {
  const user = this;
  if (!user.isModified("password")) return next();
  try {
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, SALT_ROUNDS);
    user.password = hash;
    return next();
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function comparePassword(
  candidate: string
) {
  return bcrypt.compare(candidate, this.password);
};
```

I guess it is something wrong with the import (the way I am using it). When I use require as shown (commented in the code) I don't get these errors, however I get the following error:

```
findOne is not a function
```

Can you please guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is unable to get types from your schema definition, so you have to describe them manually. Modify your `crmModel` file:

```
import { Document, Model } from "mongoose";

export interface UserDocument extends Document {
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;

  comparePassword(candidate: string): Promise<boolean> // or whatever it returns
}
export interface UserModel extends Model<UserDocument> {}

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema<UserDocument>({
  // ...
}).pre<UserDocument>('save', async function(/* ... */) { 
  // ...
})

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function(/* */) { /* ... */}

const User = mongoose.model<UserDocument, UserModel>('User', UserSchema)
export default User
```

Notice that I moved model declaration in `crmModel` file, you can just import it anywhere later, models are supposed to be created once. Also you can add any other methods you need in `UserDocument` and static methods in `UserModel`

Although I just realized, i'm unsure, why it says `findOne is not a function`, because it should be defined on any model, but I hope adding the interfaces will resolve the problem